# Powershell script to check subfolders exist or not

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I'm trying to write a script in PowerShell. There will be the main folder like eg: movies. Inside I will have a subfolder of which language of movie it is and another subfolder inside it for the movie name. I will be giving only the main folder path **ie: F:\Movies**, And I will be taking the language of the movie folder and movie name folder as parameters I want to verify if the folder is available inside the main folder or not. I wrote the below script but it's not working. Could you please help me to figure it out?

```
Function Folder_Check {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$Languageofmovie,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$nameofmovie)
   
    $Foldertocheck = 'F:\Movies'

    if ($result = Get-childitem -path $Foldertocheck -Recurse -Directory) {
        Write-Host "Folder found in $($result)"  
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "No it is not available"
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (Test-Path -Path 'F:\Movies' -PathType Container) { "Folder exists" }`. Please **remove** all version tags you do not actually use

Comment: do you REALLY need to run the code in ps2 & ps3 & ps4? the current version for windows is ps5.1, so if you don't need those other versions, remove all but the `powershell` tag.

Comment: Theo's answer really - but if I understand you correctly you want to test for the movie folder`if (Test-Path -Path "F:\Movies\$Languageofmovie\$nameofmovie" -PathType Container) { "Folder exists" }`

Comment: [Use **version tags** only if your question is *version-specific*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415770/1701026). For questions about PowerShell programming that are specific to a version use the *one* specific tag (as e.g. **[tag:powershell-2.0]**). On *all* PowerShell questions, use the general **[tag:powershell]** tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this by leveraging the parameters passed to the function.
Since you know the folder structure you can create a variable that combines the root folder, the language and the movie name:

```
Function Folder_Check {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$Languageofmovie,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$nameofmovie)
   
    $Foldertocheck = '~\Documents\Movies'
    $MovieFolder = "$Foldertocheck\$Languageofmovie\$nameofmovie"

    if (Test-Path $MovieFolder -PathType Container) {
        Write-Host "$MovieFolder found"  
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "$MovieFolder is not available"
    }
}
```

Using **-PathType Container** to make sure the movie name is a folder and not a file.

Then you can call the function - something like:

> Folder_Check English Godfather
>
> Folder_Check English Armageddon
>
> Folder_Check Russian TheIdiot

Comment: This helps me to clear the halfway. But could you tell me how do I check for the same folder in multiple drives like the C drive, E drive and etc? I tried to add a different drive but it's not working. Could you please help me with this?

 $Drives = "F","C","D"
   $MovieFolder = "$Drives\$Languageofmovie\$nameofmovie"

Answer (score 0):

Did I understand correctly?

```
Function Folder_Check {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$Languageofmovie,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$nameofmovie)
   
    $Foldertocheck = $Foldertocheck = 'F:\Movies' + '$($Languageofthemovie)'

    if ((Get-childitem -path $Foldertocheck -Directory).name -match '$($nameofmovie)') {
        Write-Host "Folder found in $($Foldertocheck)"  
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "No it is not available"
    }
}
```